# How to Convert CCSpriteBatchNode to UIImage?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, uiimage, ccsprite

I want to convert `CCSpriteBatchNode` to a `UIImage`, is there a possible way to do it? I know it is possible to convert `CCSprite` to `UIImage`, but when I try it with `CCSpriteBatchNode`, it crashes :

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'CCSpriteBatchNode should NOT be root node'
```

Thanks!

Here is the code to convert CCSprite to UIImage.

```
+ (UIImage *)renderUIImageFromSprite:(CCSprite *)sprite {
    CCRenderTexture *renderer = [CCRenderTexture renderTextureWithWidth:sprite.contentSize.width; height:sprite.contentSize.height;];
    [renderer begin];
    [sprite visit];
    [renderer end];
    return [renderer getUIImageFromBuffer];
}
```

EDIT :
This is the working code.

```
+ (UIImage *)renderUIImageFromCCLabelBMFont:(CCLabelBMFont *)bmfont {
    GLProgram *program = [[CCShaderCache sharedShaderCache] programForKey:kCCShader_PositionTextureColor];
    glUseProgram(program->program_);

    int textureWidth = bmfont.contentSize.width;
    int textureHeight = bmfont.contentSize.height;

    CCRenderTexture *renderer = [CCRenderTexture renderTextureWithWidth:textureWidth height:textureHeight];
    bmfont.anchorPoint = ccp(0.0, 0.0);

    CCNode *node = [CCNode node];
    [node addChild:bmfont];

    [renderer begin];
    [node visit];
    [renderer end];

    return [renderer getUIImageFromBuffer];
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying when it crashes? Show the code that's not working rather than the working code. From the error I would say you first need to add the CCSpriteBatchNode as a child to another node, if only temporarily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Needed this myself. This is ARC code and set up as a category for CCLabelBMFont.

### CCLabelBMFont+UIImage.h

```
@interface CCLabelBMFont (UIImage)

- (UIImage *)image;

@end
```

### CCLabelBMFont+UIImage.m

```
@implementation CCLabelBMFont (UIImage)

- (UIImage *)image
{
    CCGLProgram *program = [[CCShaderCache sharedShaderCache] programForKey:kCCShader_PositionTextureColor];
    glUseProgram(program->program_);

    CCRenderTexture *renderer = [[CCRenderTexture alloc] initWithWidth:(int)self.contentSize.width
                                                                height:(int)self.contentSize.height
                                                           pixelFormat:kCCTexture2DPixelFormat_RGBA8888];

    CCLabelBMFont *labelBMFont = [[CCLabelBMFont alloc] initWithString:string_
                                                               fntFile:fntFile_
                                                                 width:width_
                                                             alignment:alignment_
                                                           imageOffset:imageOffset_];

    labelBMFont.anchorPoint = ccp(0.0, 0.0);

    CCNode *node = [CCNode node];
    [node addChild:labelBMFont];

    [renderer begin];
    [node visit];
    [renderer end];

    return [renderer getUIImage];
}

@end
```